# How to multiply 32-bit integers in c

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, multiplication

Execution of:

```
#define HIGH32(V64) ((uint32_t)((V64 >> 32)&0xffFFffFF))
#define LOW32(V64) ((uint32_t)(V64&0xffFFffFF))

uint32_t a = 0xffFFffFF;
uint32_t b = 0xffFFffFF;
uint64_t res = a * b;
printf("res = %08X %08X\n", HIGH32(res), LOW32(res));
```

Gives:

```
"res = 00000000 00000001"
```

But I expect: fffffffe00000001. What did I do wrong? Single assignment:

```
res = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;
printf("res = %08X %08X\n", HIGH32(res), LOW32(res));
```

Gives

```
res = 01234567 89ABCDEF
```

Environment:

```
$gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ gcc -v
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/lto-wrapper.exe
dest arch: i686-pc-cygwin

$ file a.exe
a.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Comment: thanks, I thought multiplication gives result twice wider than operands

Comment: @user3479125 That's an x86 assembly thing. C gives back the same type. This is also annoying when you multiply+divide two integers, which can be done exactly in assembly, but require casting in C to do the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You currently have:

```
uint64_t res = (uint32_t) a * (uint32_t) b;
```

You will want to promote the arguments to 64bit numbers before the multiplication. Therefore:

```
uint64_t res = (uint64_t) a * b;
```