# C: two integers multiply to negative value (overflow shouldn't happen yet)

Tags: c, variables, types, multiplication

I am learning C at the moment and we got a pretty simple matrix multiplication exercise that seems to work well for most test cases. However, one case doesn't work and I already narrowed it down to this piece of code that doesn't produce the expected result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a1 = 1261373;
    int b1 = 1261373;
    int a2 = 1669717;
    int b2 = 1293027;
    long mult1 = a1*b1;
    long mult2 = a2*b2;
    printf("mult1=%ld , mult2=%ld", mult1, mult2);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
mult1=1923945609 , mult2=-1379386529
```

Instead of the expected:

```
mult1=1591061845129, mult2=2158989163359
```

Obviously, especially with the second result I thought of an overflow first. But that really shouldn't happen with such small numbers, should it? The input is definetly an integer (we can't change that) and the output should be a long so I can't change the data types and I have no idea how it gets a negative number for the second multiplication or why the first result is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `a1 * b1` is an `int`, which you’re then converting to a `long`. If you want to use `long` multiplication, cast one of them to a `long` first, as in `(long)a1 * b1`. (Also, don’t rely on `long` representing any particular number of bits. If you want an unsigned 64-bit integer, use `uint64_t`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply 32-bit integers in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203425/how-to-multiply-32-bit-integers-in-c)

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved the problem, I had no idea you had to cast it to a long first but now all testcases work correctly :)

Comment: @Ryan, you should post that as an answer...

Comment: pay attention please that `long` isn't 64 bit on all platforms, even on x64 platforms , see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155784/range-of-values-in-c-int-and-long-32-64-bits

Comment: "Such small numbers".  Times change.  The product you're trying to compute is 2158989163359, which is a 41-bit number.  So it'll work on a 64-bit machine, if you cast to `long` first, as other comments/answers have advised.  But it still won't work on a machine where longs are "only" 32 bits.

Comment: If you think about the rule, "multiplying two `int`s creates an `int` in C", that's rather easy to remember actually. On the other hand, [integer promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/) is what most C programmers sadly don't know (in my opinion, out of 10 randomly chosen C programmers, 2 will know promotion rules), and *that* will produce strange results if you are not aware of it.

Comment: @Groo I'm aware of integer promotion, and I still think it produces strange results at times.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a1 = 1261373;
    int b1 = 1261373;
    int a2 = 1669717;
    int b2 = 1293027;
    long mult1 = (long long)a1*b1; //Type cast one operand to long long
    long mult2 = (long long)a2*b2;
    printf("mult1=%ld , mult2=%ld", mult1, mult2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, I had to cast it BEFORE multiplying. Now it works :)

Comment: this solution isn't portable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155784/range-of-values-in-c-int-and-long-32-64-bits

Comment: yes it will, can you edit the answer so I remove my downvote :)